# installing zookeeper telnet gives error

Tags: apache-kafka

after installing zookeeperd it is not listening on the port 2181.
In telnet :-
"ruok" command not giving result as "imok"

```
kafka@DNilesh-PC:~$ telnet localhost 2181
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet> ruok
?Invalid command
telnet>
```

it is expected to say `imok`

Comment: Strange, it should work.

[user@host]$ telnet localhost 2181
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ruok
imokConnection closed by foreign host.

Answer (score 3):

As per log line `Connected to localhost` your `zookeeper` is listening on port `2181` that is because you were connected through telnet.

Coming to `ruok` command, you can use `nc` as mentioned in zookeeper documentation below:

> `ruok:` Tests if server is running in a non-error state. The server
>   will respond with imok if it is running. Otherwise it will not respond
>   at all.
>
> A response of "imok" does not necessarily indicate that the server has
>   joined the quorum, just that the server process is active and bound to
>   the specified client port. Use "stat" for details on state wrt quorum
>   and client connection information.

Proper usage of  `ruok` command is:

```
> echo ruok | nc localhost 2181
which gives you output `imok`
```

You can find more information about these `Four Letter Word commands` [here](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to escape ?
just type in `ruok` i.e

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
ruok
imokConnection closed by foreign host.
```